# SQLplus row limiting

Tags: sql, bash, sqlplus

Is there a setting like `SET ROW LIMIT 100` That I can use to limit the output of sqlplus? This is the command I've written already and I'm hoping I can keep my html more manageable.

`sqlplus -S -L user@host <<EOF
SET MARKUP HTML ON
SPOOL output.html
START script.sql
EXIT
EOF`

Edit: This is going in a script, to get a preview of a sql command's output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** If this is fine with you, try to restrict the output in query itself, following worked when I tested it in `sqlplus`

```
select * from (SELECT column1, column2 FROM dm_singh_test_table) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

---

Could you please try following in `sqlplus` and let me know if this helps.

```
SQL> set pause on
SQL> set pages 10 pause 'press enter in case you want to continue'
SQL> select field_name from your_table;
```